# Compiler error using macro method call with ternary

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

The compiler marks my ternary operator and says that it expected `]` instead of `kGraySquare`.
What did do I wrong?

```
#define kGreenSquare [UIImage imageNamed@"distance_on"]
#define kGraySquare [UIImage imageNamed@"distance_off"]

@implementation DistanceIndicatorView
{
    NSMutableArray<UIImageView*>*items;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     items = [[NSMutableArray<UIImageView*> alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
     NSInteger offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        [items addObject:[[UIImageView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offset, 0, 8, 8)]];
        [items[i] setImage:_distance<i?kGreenSquare:kGraySquare];
         offset += 10;
    }

}
```

Comment: You missed `:` Try [UIImage imageNamed:@"distance_on"]

Comment: So stupid mistake! Thank you, iYoung!!!

Comment: Can you please mark answer as accepted if this answers your question?

Comment: This is exactly why you should not use this language element. It is highly error prone, not type safe at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed `:`

Add colon (:) & update like below

```
#define kGreenSquare [UIImage imageNamed:@"distance_on"]
#define kGraySquare [UIImage imageNamed:@"distance_off"]
```

This will work fine.